# How can i fix my code its not calling a float?

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate a spamicity for a Bayesian formula, but I get this error:

```
 error TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Here's my code:

```
spamicities = sorted(
    map(self.classify_word(body) ,re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  body).split()),
    key=lambda x: abs(x-0.5),
    reverse=True)[:38]
```

Comment: `self.classify_word(body)` -> `lambda body: self.classify_word(body)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying your problem a little bit. Take a look at

```
map(self.classify_word(body) ,re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  body).split())
```

This line won't work because `self.classify_word(body)` is replaced by a `Float` value, so the line becomes something like

```
map(5.0 ,re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  body).split())  # wrong!
```

You need a callable as the first argument, so wrap it in an anonymous function as follows:

```
map(lambda x: self.classify_word(x) ,re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  body).split())
```

Comment: if i want to put instead of self.classify_word(x) a self.example which is calculated in another function in the same class ,how can i call it there??

Comment: I'm not following - why can't you replace `self.classify_word(x)` with that other function?

Comment: i am not putting a function its a value calculated in another function in the same class

Comment: and i want to put only that one not the whole function there

Comment: but i am getting error: object has no attribute 'example'

Comment: If it's a pre-calculated value, then your output array won't depend on the input array, so why would you be using `map`? Your output will be list of values which are all exactly the same.

Comment: Try posting another question, with the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
 spamicities = sorted(
                map(lambda body: self.classify_word(body) ,re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  body).split()),
                key=lambda x: abs(x-0.5),
                reverse=True
                )[:38]
```

Comment: @alex if this helped please reward best-anwser. Thankyou